# SignalRHelper how to authorize by http with base url, and for connecting to ws use another ws url with another baseUrl

Tags: angular, signalr, azure-api-management, aspnetboilerplate, abp

We are using asp.net zero + angular.

How we can authorize connection by http with **AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl** but connect to ws by another url ?

Or maybe we can configure another way to authorize our connection.

Ignore authorize is not correct solution.

We are using Azure API Management where is supporting WebSocket, but we need 2 different endpoint routes for it, because you can`t create route to your API:
`http(s)://{base_url}` and `ws(s)://{base_url}`,
you must add difference by using suffix, like :

```
http(s)://{base_url}
ws(s)://{base_url}/{suffix}
```

or

```
http(s)://{base_url}/{suffix}
ws(s)://{base_url}
```

Error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOtgO.png)

```
import { AppConsts } from '@shared/AppConsts';
import { LocalStorageService } from '@shared/utils/local-storage.service';

export class SignalRHelper {
    static initSignalR(callback: () => void): void {
        new LocalStorageService().getItem(
            AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName,
            function (err, value) {
                let encryptedAuthToken = value?.token;

                abp.signalr = {
                    autoConnect: false, // _zone.runOutsideAngular in ChatSignalrService
                    // autoReconnect: true,
                    connect: undefined,
                    hubs: undefined,
                    qs: encryptedAuthToken
                        ? AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName +
                          '=' +
                          encodeURIComponent(encryptedAuthToken)
                        : '',
                    remoteServiceBaseUrl: AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl,
                    startConnection: undefined,
                    url: '/signalr',
                };

                let script = document.createElement('script');
                script.onload = () => {
                    callback();
                };

                script.src = AppConsts.appBaseUrl + '/assets/abp/abp.signalr-client.js';
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Dependecies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.14",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.0",
    "abp-ng2-module": "6.3.0",
    "abp-web-resources": "^5.4.0",
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.17",
    "angular-gridster2": "^11.1.3",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.2",
    "angular2-counto": "^1.2.5",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.9.0",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "just-compare": "^1.3.0",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^1.26.0",
    "memoizee": "^0.4.15",
    "msal": "^1.4.6",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.5",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "11.0.2",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "primeflex": "^3.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.4.5",
    "push.js": "^1.0.12",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "remixicon": "^2.5.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rtl-detect": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.15.5",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.8",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

Comment: As you have already started an issue on GitHub, adding reference to help other community members. You can refer to [SignalRHelper authorization](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/6305)